# Debugging breaks on Rails's "break" in ActiveSupport::Callbacks.run

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activesupport

Ruby-debug is getting hung up by breaking on the "break" ruby reserved word on line 94 activesupport-2.3.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb.

```
  def run(object, options = {}, &terminator)
    enumerator = options[:enumerator] || :each

    unless block_given?
      send(enumerator) { |callback| callback.call(object) }
    else
      send(enumerator) do |callback|
        result = callback.call(object)
        break result if terminator.call(result, object) # This line is the culprit
      end
    end
  end
```

I know break is a reserved word in Ruby and I'm surpirsed that the ruby-debug is breaking on the word "break" for each ActiveSupport callback.  This has rendered almost all of my debugging useless as the callback is triggered very frequently.  I am no longer able to run any of my rspec tests as the callback breakpoint is triggered many times for each spec.

Here is a list of all of my currently installed gems: http://pastie.org/854538

Update:
I tried removing ruby-debug and ruby-debug-base and now I get the following message when ever I run my specs.  I am reinstalling these gems as I need them.

```
debugger statement ignored, use -u or --debugger option on rspec to enable debugging
```

I do not know how to get around this.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out why this is happening.  I looked at what method was responsible for triggering the callback and I realized it was one of my own with a "debugger" break point in it.  I was just confusing to see the debugger break in ActiveSupport::Callbacks.  My debugger break point was at the last line of the method so the debugger naturally went to the next executable line which was in ActiveSupport::Callbacks.run.  Thanks Igal for the help with this.